# Analytic continuation along curves

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g$ be a holomorphic function defined in the neighborhood of $i$ as the branch of $\sqrt {1-z^{2}}$ which satisfies $g(i)=\sqrt 2$.
(1).Show that $g$ can be continued analytically along any curve in $\mathbb{C}\backslash\left\{-1,1\right\}$
(2).Can $g$ be continued analytically to define a holomorphic function on $G$?Why?
(3).Show that the analytic continuation of $g$ leads to a holomorphic function on $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\backslash \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}:-1\leq x\leq1 \right\}$

I know that $g$ has two branch points,say$+i$ and $i$.So the value of $g$  at the same point would change if it moves from this point along a curve whose interior contains only $+i$ or $-i$.If we make a cut between $i$ and $-i$,the circumstance above would never happen and the continuation we've got is a single-value analytic function. But I don't know how to express this in strict mathmetical language since this is a problem in prelim exam.

Comment: What is the set $G$?

Comment: @Ryan $G=\mathbb{C}  \backslash \left\{-1,1\right\}$